# Dynamic colors in graphs

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I try to load colors dynamicly with jquery.

This is working:

```
 var colors_array= ["#9CC4E4", "#3A89C9", "#F26C4F"];

Morris.Donut({

  element: 'donut-example',
   colors: colors_array,
  data: [
    {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},
    {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
    {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
  ]
});
```

Desired result (does not work):

```
   function graphDonut(colors) {
            var value = colors;
            value = value.replace(/\|/g,'", "');
            var colors_array = '["' + value + '"]';

        Morris.Donut({

          element: 'donut-example',
           colors: colors_array,
          data: [
            {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},
            {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
            {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
          ]
        });

    }

graphDonut("#9CC4E4|#3A89C9|#F26C4F");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to replace

```
var colors_array = '["' + value + '"]';
```

with

```
var colors_array = value.split("|");
```

It gives me this output:

```
["#9CC4E4", "#3A89C9", "#F26C4F"]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

split the string or pass an array, the latter would be easier

```
function graphDonut(colors) {

    Morris.Donut({
        element: 'donut-example',
        colors : colors,
        data   : [
            {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},
            {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
            {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
        ]
    });
}

graphDonut( ['#9CC4E4', '#3A89C9', '#F26C4F'] );
```

or

```
function graphDonut(colors) {
    var arr = colors.split('|');

    Morris.Donut({
        element: 'donut-example',
        colors : arr,
        data   : [
            {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},
            {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
            {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
        ]
    });
}

graphDonut("#9CC4E4|#3A89C9|#F26C4F");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code

```js
Morris.Donut({

  element: 'donut-example',
   colors: ["#9CC4E4", "#3A89C9", "#F26C4F"],
  data: [
    {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},
    {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
    {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
  ]
});
```

I was getting same issue, I am sharing my corrected code as below

```js
 new Morris.Donut({
     element: "MyChart",
     colors: ["#9CC4E4", "#3A89C9", "#F26C4F"],
     data: object2
  });
```

[image: Do nut Chart Colorful view]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script> 
    new Morris.Donut({
        element: 'donut-example',
        data: [
            {label: "Serie 1", value: 12},
            {label: "Serie 2", value: 30},
            {label: "Serie 3", value: 20},
            {label: "Serie 3", value: 20}
        ],
        colors: ['#a6d000', '#0070e7', '#e700b5', '#ffab17'],
        xkey: 'y',
        ykeys: ['vaue']
    });
</script>
```